# How can I rename a PySpark dataframe column by index? (handle duplicated column names)

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have an issue where I need to dynamically update columns in a Spark dataframe.

Basically I need to loop through the column list and if the column exists already in the list, rename it to that column plus its index.

My attempted code was something like this:

```
def dup_cols(df):
  for i, icol in enumerate(df.columns):
    for x, xcol in enumerate(df.columns):
      if icol == xcol and i != x:
        df = df.withColumnsRenamed(xcol, xcol + '_' + str(x))
  return df
```

But this renames by name (here as *xcol*), thus not solving my issue.

Can I change this to rename the column in the dataframe by its index?  I have searched around for quite a while and found nothing.

I also cannot convert to a Pandas dataframe, so I would need a Spark/PySpark solution to renaming a specific column by its index only.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF) to rename the columns:

> Returns a new class:*DataFrame* that with new specified column names

Here is an example:

```python
data = [
    (1, 2, 3),
    (4, 5, 6),
    (7, 8, 9)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["a", "b", "a"])
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- a: long (nullable = true)
# |-- b: long (nullable = true)
# |-- a: long (nullable = true)
```

Create new names based on your index logic:

```python
new_names = []
counter = {c: -1 for c in df.columns}
for c in df.columns:
    new_c = c
    counter[c] += 1
    new_c += str(counter[c]) if counter[c] else ""
    new_names.append(new_c)
print(new_names)
#['a', 'b', 'a1']
```

Now use `toDF()` to create a new DataFrame with the new column names:

```python
df = df.toDF(*new_names)
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- a: long (nullable = true)
# |-- b: long (nullable = true)
# |-- a1: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thank you - this will work for my purposes.  
I must ask though, is there no way to say "rename this column at this index" instead of creating an entirely new dataframe as in your code?  
(Although, I can see the engine doing this anyway if there was such a function/method call)

Answer (score -1):

Suppose dt is current dataframe

```
new_columns = []

for i in range(1, len(dt.columns)):

   new_columns.append("new_column_name)

for c, n in zip(dt.columns[1:], new_columns):

    dt = dt.withColumnRenamed(c, n)
```